# Replace number with double quotes from csv file using vi editor

Tags: regex, vim, vi

I have a CSV file containing the data like below -

```
"Rank","Domain","Open Page Rank"
"1","fonts.googleapis.com","10.00"
"2","facebook.com","10.00"
"3","twitter.com","10.00"
"4","google.com","10.00"
"5","youtube.com","10.00"
"6","instagram.com","10.00"
"7","s.w.org","10.00"
"8","ajax.googleapis.com","10.00"
"9","linkedin.com","10.00"
```

How can I remove double quotes from all numbers here using vi editor or similar effect?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Just write a regex, that matches a `"`, then any digit or a dot one or more times, then a `"`, and substitute that for the thing inside `"`.

Comment: I was using perl - perl -ne 's/"(\d+)"/$1/g; print' file.csv > new.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a regex search and replace:

```
%s/"\(\d\+\(\.\d\+\)\?\)"/\1/g
```

"on every line in the file, find...
   all strings that start with a double quote...
   followed by one or more digits...
     optionally, followed by a period, which is followed by one or more digits...
   followed by a double quote...
   replace the string with the outer capture group...
   and do it everywhere it appears on the line.
"

Comment: Correct solution for this is %s/"\(\d\+\(\.\d\+\)\?\)"/\1/g. %s/"\(\d\+\(\.\d\+\)\?\)"/\1\2/g , will not treat decimals properly

Comment: ah, you're right, the inner capture group should not be inserted twice. I updated it.